# RxJava - combine concat and merge but check ALL concated observables

Tags: java, android, merge, concatenation, rx-java

I'm loading data from multiple sources AND cache them.

What I do is following:

- load data from multiple sources
- cache the results in memory

What I want is following:

1. load all needed data
2. concat the results and only propagate the result if ALL data is available

A simple example is following:

```
mObservable1 = Observable
    .concat(mObservable1Cached, mObservable1)
    .first();
```

How can I combine many caches and not cached observables like in the above example with only 1? That's my idea, but this won't work, as it will propagate a result as soon as 1 of the two observables has a cached data...

```
mObservable1And2  = Observable
    .concat(
            Observable.merge(mObservable1Cached, mObservable2Cached),
            Observable.merge(mObservable1, mObservable2)
    )
    .first();
```

**Observables example**

*Cached data observable*

```
mObservable1Cached = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<List<Data>>() {
    @Override
    public void call(Subscriber<? super List<Data>> subscriber) {
        subscriber.onNext(mData1Cached);
        subscriber.onCompleted();
    }
})
        .subscribeOn(HandlerScheduler.from(mBackgroundHandler))
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

*Loading data observable*

```
mObservable1 = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<List<Data>>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super List<Data>> subscriber) {
            subscriber.onNext(...load data...);
            subscriber.onCompleted();
        }
    })
    .doOnNext(new Action1<List<Data>>() {
        @Override
        public void call(List<Data> data) {
            mData1Cached = data;
        }
    })
    .subscribeOn(HandlerScheduler.from(mBackgroundHandler))
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

Comment: Does the Zip operator help you? This will only emit, once all Observables being zipped emit?

Answer (score 0):

this feels similar to the rx pattern for how to get form submission.  When working with a UI that contains 2 form fields, you only want to enable the submit button when both have values present.  RxJava lets you do this with a combineLatest operator.  Whenever an observable emits an item, it will combine with the last emitted item from the other emitting observable.  If only one observable has emitted so far it waits for the other one to emit and then passes both those values.

CombineLatest is my guess at how to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

zip() can do the trick.

Here is the complete (java8) solution.
If you are bounded to java7 it is trivial to refactor thought it would be much more verbose.
Also with zip you can deal with arbitrary number of sources (not just fixed count).

```
  //Dummy data
  static class Data {
    static Map<String, AtomicInteger> dataVersion = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    int sourceId;
    int itemId;
    int version;

    Data(int sourceId, int itemId) {
      this.sourceId = sourceId;
      this.itemId = itemId;
      //for testing purpose we going to track how many items created for each source/item pair
      //we always expect one
      AtomicInteger versionCounter = dataVersion.computeIfAbsent(sourceId + "." + itemId, key->new AtomicInteger());
      this.version = versionCounter.incrementAndGet();
    }
    public String toString() {
      return sourceId + "." + itemId + "; version: " + version;
    }
  };

  //data cache (per source)
  ConcurrentMap<Integer, List<Data>> sourceCache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

  //data loader
  List<Data> loadData(int sourceId) {
    return Arrays.asList(new Data(sourceId,1), new Data(sourceId,2), new Data(sourceId,3));
  }

  //source observable factory method
  Observable<List<Data>> getSource(int sourceId) {
    return Observable.<List<Data>>create(subscriber->{
      subscriber.onNext(sourceCache.computeIfAbsent(sourceId, key->loadData(key)));
      subscriber.onCompleted();
    });
  }

  public void stackOverflow33296442() {

    Observable<List<Data>> result = Observable.zip(getSource(1), getSource(2), (src1,src2)->Arrays.asList(src1,src2))
        .concatMap(listOfLists->Observable.from(listOfLists));

    //Test
    Iterator<List<Data>> iter1 = result.toBlocking().toIterable().iterator();
    while (iter1.hasNext()) {
      List<Data> next = iter1.next();
      System.out.println("data: " + next);
      for (Data data : next) {
        assert 1 == data.version;
      }
    }

    Iterator<List<Data>> iter2 = result.toBlocking().toIterable().iterator();
    while (iter2.hasNext()) {
      List<Data> next = iter2.next();
      System.out.println("data: " + next);
      for (Data data : next) {
        assert 1 == data.version;
      }
    }
  }
```

Output:

```
data: [1.1; version: 1, 1.2; version: 1, 1.3; version: 1]
data: [2.1; version: 1, 2.2; version: 1, 2.3; version: 1]
data: [1.1; version: 1, 1.2; version: 1, 1.3; version: 1]
data: [2.1; version: 1, 2.2; version: 1, 2.3; version: 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for blocking till completion of the concatenated observables which can be achieved like this:

```
mObservable1 = Observable
  .concat(mObservable1Cached, mObservable1)
  .toList()
  .flatMapIterable(x -> x)
  .first();
```